# PHP как удалить все теги <a> вокруг <img>?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

К примеру

```
$content='<a href="/link1"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a><a href="/link2">link2</a><a href="/link3"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a>';
```

как оставить?

```
<img src="image1.jpg" /><a href="/link2">link2</a><img src="image2.jpg" />
```

Comment: Если `html` всегда такой, можно воспользоваться `strip_tags`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/<a.*?>(<img.*?)<\/a>(<a.*?<\/a>).*?(<img.*?>).*/','\1\2\3',$content);
```

Comment: Регулярка не работает если есть перенос строки допустим: $content='<a href="/link1"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a> (перенос строки)
<a href="/link2">link2</a><a href="/link3"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a>';

Comment: где возможен перенос, можно добавить \s?
preg_replace('/<a.*?>(<img.*?)<\/a>\s?(<a.*?<\/a>).*?(<img.*?>).*/','\1\2\3',$content);
Если добавлять \s? внутри скобок, перенос будет и в конечном варианте.
Например
preg_replace('/<a.*?>(<img.*?)<\/a>(\s?<a.*?<\/a>).*?(<img.*?>).*/','\1\2\3',$content);

Answer (score 0):

Например, так

```
$text = preg_replace('#<a[a-zA-Z0-9\=\/\s\"]*>#', '', $content, 1);
$text = substr($text,0,-4);
```

Первым выражением удалением тег "a" вначале строки, вторым удаляем заключительный
Перевод строк не является помехой в этом варианте

Answer (score 0):

> *как оставить? `<img src="image1.jpg" /><a href="/link2">link2</a><img src="image2.jpg" />`*

```
$content = '<a href="/link1"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a><a href="/link2">link2</a><a href="/link3"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a>';

$content = preg_replace('~<a[^>]*>(?=\s*<img)|/>\K\s*</a>~', '', $content);

echo $content;
```

Answer (score -2):

`<img src="image2.jpg" href ="/page" />`
Переместил атрибут в картинку. О - Оптимизация